# When to register a method that will call Form.Invoke to an event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, invoke

I get the following exception in a Windows Form application

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

The method where the exception occurs calls this.Invoke (System.Windows.Forms.Form.Invoke). This method is registered to the event of another class in the constructor, which seems to lead to a race condition and this exception.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SomeOtherClass.Instance.MyEvent += new SomeDelegate(MyMethod);
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        // ... some code ...
    }
}
```

At which stage of the form lifecycle is the Handle created? In which event of the form would it be safe to register the method to the foreign event?

Comment: It looks like you're not calling InitializeComponent() in your constructor.

Comment: There is **HandleCreated** event for forms you may check that

Comment: @bitxwise, I'm calling InitializeComponent first in the constructor, I just left it out of the code sample to simplyfy ... I will add it again.

Comment: @V4Vendetta, thanks, I will try this ... maybe you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I now changed it to this:

```
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
}
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    SomeOtherClass.Instance.MyEvent += new SomeDelegate(MyMethod);
}
private void MyMethod()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        // ... some code ...
    }
}
```

an alternative version would be

```
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
    SomeOtherClass.Instance.MyEvent += new SomeDelegate(MyMethod);
}
private void MyMethod()
{
    if (this.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            // ... some code ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your alternative version is not a cleaner solution as every time event fired a redundant check is made whether Handle is created.

Comment: Therefore I chose the first version ;-)

Comment: don't forget to select an answer that best fits your needs ;-).

Comment: ok, done ... since V4Vendetta didn't post her/his comment as an answer, I had to choose mine ...

Answer (score 2):

I think if you register the method in OnShow event you should be safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you just thinking this or are there facts/sources to support your opinion?

Comment: @Hinek: when the OnShow event is risen, form has been showed for the first time, so every graphical handle has been created. I cannot tell I'm sure it works 100% because I can't test it right now, but I'm pretty sure...

Comment: @Hinek: if inside OnShown() event you check this.IsHandleCreated, you see it's true

Answer (score 2):

Put the InitializeComponent() call back before you register the handler, as suggested by bitxwise

You'll get the same problem when the form is disposed so unregsiter the handler then.

You could do somthing like `if(this.IsHandleCreated)` in your handler to be safe.

Comment: I already have a call to InitializeComponent and unregister the handler, I just wanted to show the code as simple as possible in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned already `IsHandleCreated` is the way to go.
Following snippet tells how to do that.

```
public class TestEvent : Form
{

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        MyMethod();

    }
    private void MyMethod()
    {

        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                   {
                                      //Here goes your code.
                                   }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but neither does your code make any sense nor are you using IsHandleCreated, as you mention before...

Comment: Sure this method will be called just after handle is created. protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)